# networkx stress centrality for directed graph

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

Is this code correct for directed graph? Can this code be written without using map()? Does the `g` mean a graph which consists node? How can I use this after `G=karate_club_graph()` and input this `G` in  `stress_centrality(G)`?

```
def stress_centrality(g):
  stress = defaultdict(int)

  for a in nx.nodes_iter(g):
    for b in nx.nodes_iter(g):
      if a==b:
        continue
      # pred = nx.predecessor(G,b)  # for unweighted graphs
      pred, distance = nx.dijkstra_predecessor_and_distance(g,b)  # for weighted graphs
      if not pred.has_key(a):
        return [] 
      path = [[a,0]] 
      path_length = 1
      index = 0
      while index >= 0: 
        n,i = path[index] 
        if n == b: 
          for vertex in map(lambda x:x[0], path[:index+1])[1:-1]:
            stress[vertex] += 1
        if len(pred[n]) > i: 
          index += 1 
          if index == path_length: 
            path.append([pred[n][i],0]) 
            path_length += 1 
          else: 
            path[index] = [pred[n][i],0] 
        else: 
          index -= 1 
          if index >= 0: 
            path[index][4] += 1 
  return stress
```

Comment: what is stress centrality?

Comment: And have you tested this on any networks whose results you know?

Comment: You seem to have a lot of questions here, including those as basic as "how do I call a function?" Take a look at [ask]. Joel's questions are pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: how can i use this without " for vertex in map(lambda x:x[0], path[:index+1])[1:-1]:"....specially not using map() ...... @joel

Comment: how can i use this without " for vertex in map(lambda x:x[0], path[:index+1])[1:-1]:"....specially not using map() ...... @aryamccarthy

Comment: What's wrong with using `map`?

Comment: TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You __cannot__ have `has_key` work and also get the error you're getting. `has_key` was removed from Python 3, while `map` is only not subscriptable in Python 3. Which are you using? Anyway, wrap each `map(foo)[bar]` with `list()` like this: `list(map(foo))[bar]`.

Comment: im using 3.6....is there any alternative way to use has_key  in 3.6? @Joel

Comment: im using 3.6....is there any alternative way to use has_key  in 3.6?....
@aryamccarthy

Comment: Yes, the preference is to use `if a not in pred:`.

Comment: path[index][4] += 1 
IndexError: list index out of range